# Setting min input for datetime-local restricts only the date but not the hours

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to get the user to input only a date-time in the future, but the date picker only limits dates but not hours and minutes, so eventually the user is allowed to pick a date-time that is bellow the set min value. What am I doing wrong?

```
    let dateTime = new Date()
    dateTime.setMinutes(dateTime.getMinutes() - dateTime.getTimezoneOffset())
    taskdate.value = dateTime.toISOString().slice(0, -8)
    taskdate.min = dateTime.toISOString().slice(0, -8)
```

The element itself looks just fine to me:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="#" id="taskdate" min="2023-11-09T22:15">
```

but I can still select 2023-11-09T12:00 for example, although everything before 2023-11-09, like 2022-11-09 is disabled.

I tried playing with different date-time formats but can't get my date picker to implement the restriction on hours and minutes.